# JQuery Mobile and Google Maps Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am simply trying to display a google map within a jquery mobile page.  If I load the page directly it works.  However, if I navigate to the page from another page it only renders a single map tile.  At first glance it would appear that my issue was similar to https://forum.jquery.com/topic/google-maps-inside-jquery-mobile

However, I was already performing my initialization within the 'pageinit' event and my map div has a set width and height.

I have seen http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/ but I would rather not use a (another) third party plugin if at all possible.

Here's what my page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="global.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapPage" data-role="page">
        <style type="text/css">
            html
            {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body
            {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map_canvas
            {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***API_KEY_REMOVED***&sensor=true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var height = $(window).height() - 50;
                var width = $(window).width();

                $("#map_canvas").height(height);
                $("#map_canvas").width(width);
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.962799, -82.999802);
                var myOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 18,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
                //alert($(map.getDiv()).width());   
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: ""
                });
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
            }

            $("#mapPage").live('pageinit', function () {

                initialize();
            });

        </script>
        <div data-role="header" id="menuHeader">
            <a href="MenuDialog.htm" class="menuLink" data-role="none" data-rel="dialog">
                <img class="headerIcon" style="height: 40px; border-right: 1px solid #333333; padding-right: 5px;"
                    id="MenuIcon" src="images/menuIcon.png" /></a>
            <p>
                Loc
            </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="margin-top: 50px;">
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

**Update:**

After some experimenting I added the following delay to my resize event:

```
setTimeout(function() {

            google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
        }, 500);
```

This seemed to fix the issue. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Timeout function was exactly the thing that I need. Cheers

Comment: This works fantastically. While I feel it's quite hackey, there aren't a lot of options here. The timeout works great as it allows the map to render first before calling this to ensure a proper sizing. My only issue here is how can we be sure 500 ms is enough? A callback approach may work better, such as listening for the map to fire it's "idle" event. Idle didn't work for me though and I couldn't find another appropriate event to hook into. :(

Comment: setTimeout works great.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `<html>` and `<body>` at 100% size, but not the `<div>`s in the hierarchy between `<body>` and `<div id="map_canvas">`.

Try adding those to your CSS as well (the `content` one will need an `id`).

You may also need to ensure that the API knows the size of the map `<div>` by triggering a `resize` event when everything is ready. Showing only a single tile is a classic symptom of the API getting it wrong (and generally assuming it has zero size).

Comment: The only div between the body and the map div is the "content" div, which I don't actually want to be 100%. I would like the map to display below the header. Like I said, the map is displaying correctly when I load the page without going through a link, so I don't think it's simply a style based issue...

Comment: That's handled by the JQuery Mobile framework styling.  I went ahead and gave your suggestion a shot by manually overriding the style anyway and it's as I suspected, that's not the problem. The problem appears to be with the interaction between the JQuery Mobile page loading method and the Google maps API, but I can't figure out what that issue is...

Comment: @Shawn: Actually in your snippet there's `<div id="mapPage" data-role="page">` in the hierarchy as well (it doesn't appear to have a `</div>` tag).

Comment: That's a good catch, but unfortunately it doesn't look like it's the actual issue either.  It's still showing the same behavior.  JQueryMobile loads the content of the "page" div dynamically. At the time of the initialization it appears as though there is indeed a set width and height on the map canvas div, but for some reason it's behaving like there isn't.

Comment: @Shawn: Edited answer to include a `resize` event. Sounds like things are happening in the wrong order and the API isn't being told the right information about the size.

Comment: In my code I am actually calling the "resize" event during initialization, but it didn't seem to be having an effect.  After setting a timeout and delaying the resize event I was able to get it to work, thought there is a slight delay.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13):

I read on a website that if you have this problem it's beacuse the dom isn't totally loaded when you initialize your google map.
You must add this in your code:

```
$( document ).bind( "pageshow", function( event, data ){
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

It works for me. It's maybe brutal to resize at every page you show but ... it works.

Comment: correct answer instead of triggering the resize method, we would invoke the map after the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of firing a resize, I solved this by wrapping my js in a 'pagecreate' event... like this:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#map', function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.773782,-73.974236),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };  

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right approach would be to trigger the event when partial tile is loaded once. Below code snippet will help you in achieving that.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue for me was that JQuery mobile uses Ajax to load the pages. I am not sure if it is the best practice but I simply forced it to load my map page normally by putting the following code in the anchor tag:

```
data-ajax="false"
```